# vue.js Multiselect error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

2 days I'm searching in this error and tried many ways but not worked i don't know this bug or what and no result I'm using vue.js ver 2.1.10 and laravel 5.4.
my template.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
       <multiselect v-model="value" :options="options">
       </multiselect>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import axios from 'axios'   //similar to vue-resource
    import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

    export default {
        components: { Multiselect },
        props: ['title'],
        data(){
            return{
                model: {
                    'title':'',
                    'desc':'',
                },
                value: [],
                options: ['list', 'of', 'options'],
            }
        },
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right version of `vue-multiselect`?

Comment: I'm using vue-multiselect@1.1.4

Comment: That version is for Vue 1. https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect/projects

Comment: thanks for your help i installed that component for vue 2 and i got this error [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <multiselect> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: thanks I found the solution Vue.component('multiselect', Multiselect);

Answer (score 0):

Please show the props definition of the multiselect document. Looks like you named one "key" who can't be used as a prop's name because it's reserved for v-for items

Comment: Please post this as comment, because this can't be answer.Also you will prevent yourself from being downvoted.

Comment: I would love to, but this is a new account, and I can't comment. Will edit this answer